# Rails: before_filter to exclude elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, before-filter

In my rails-app I have 2 models, let's call them **Element** and **Type**.
`:elements has_and_belongs_to_many :types`
and
`:types has_and_belongs_to_many :elements`

Now in the Element model I want to exclude some types, smth like:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_filter :exclude_some_types

 def exclude_some_types
   # if certain type satisfies condition, exclude it from the types list
 end
```

HOW can I code that? I mean the exclude part.

THX

Comment: `before_filter` is for controllers; I think you want to use `before_save`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Comment: It seems to me that you would just want to exclude the types from whatever form you are using to set up your relationship.  To do that I would just use a helper method in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `element.types.delete_if{|t| condition(t)}` work?